# How might I check if any mocha tests failed from within an after block?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

```
describe('some tests', function () {
  /*
   * Run some tests...
   */
})

after(function () {
  failures = ? // <--- what goes here?
  console.log(failures + " tests failed!")
})
```

I'd use this to keep chromedriver's browser open if a test failed, and to [report success or failure to sauce labs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#alternative-annotation-methods).

Mocha's Runner and Reporters [have the info I'm looking for](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/base.js#L257) as `stats` but I'm not sure how to get to them from within a test file.

Comment: Opened an issue on Mocha: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/1139

Answer (score 9):

I found answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194672/detecting-test-failures-from-within-aftereach-hooks-in-mocha)

```
afterEach(function() {
  if (this.currentTest.state == 'failed') {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP is not asking how to determine in an `afterEach` hook whether the test that executed just before it failed. The OP is asking how to determine in an `after` hook if *any* test after which the `after` hook is run failed.

Comment: oops sorry didn't realize it.  hopefully this will help someone like me who was looking for `afterEach` solution.

Comment: It's easy enough to put this code in the `afterEach` hook, set a flag, and check that flag in the `after` hook.

Comment: If you use `suite` and `test` instead of `describe` and `it`, this won't work. But there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661128/how-to-check-in-the-teardown-method-of-mocha-tdd-if-the-current-test-failed

Answer (score 6):

After a quick check of the code, I believe there is no way for code in `after` to have access to the runner or the reporters. However, there's a way to get the state of the tests at run time:

```
describe("blah", function () {

    it("blah", function () {
        throw new Error("blah");
    });

    after(function (){
        var failed = false;
        var tests = this.test.parent.tests;
        for(var i = 0, limit = tests.length; !failed && i < limit; ++i)
            failed = tests[i].state === "failed";
        if (failed)
            console.log("FAILED");
    });
});
```

Look at the line `var tests = this.test.parent.tests`. I believe that `this.test` seems to be a test object associated with the `after` call. The value of `this.test.parent` is the suite object associated with the top level `describe`. And the value of `this.test.parent.tests` is the list of tests in that suite. So the code there goes through each test, and detects whether the test is in the `"failed"` state.

None of the variables used in the code above are marked as private (by use of a leading underscore in the name). At the same time, there are no guarantees that future versions of Mocha will use the exact same structure.

All test failures are exceptions so to catch hook failures, I'd wrap the hook with code that detects exceptions. This is a proof-of-concept that shows how it could be done (and I've moved some of the code in the previous example into a `has_failed` function):

```
var hook_failure = false;
function make_wrapper(f) {
    return function wrapper() {
        try {
            f.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        catch (e) {
            hook_failure = true;
            throw e;
        }
    };
}

function has_failed(it) {
    var failed = false;
    var tests = it.test.parent.tests;
    for(var i = 0, limit = tests.length; !failed && i < limit; ++i)
        failed = tests[i].state === "failed";
    return failed;
}

describe("blah", function () {

    before(make_wrapper(function () {
        throw new Error("yikes!");
    }));

    it("blah", function () {
        throw new Error("q");
    });

    after(function (){
        var failed = has_failed(this);
        if (failed)
            console.log(this.test.parent.title + " FAILED");
    });
});

after(function () {
    if (hook_failure)
        console.log("HOOK FAILURE");
});
```

In the example above I use the wrapper method *and* the method of scanning tests in `after`. However, it would be possible to only use wrappers throughout for hooks *and* tests.

Comment: thanks for the investigation.  WD uses a [similar strategy](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/91993b7f1c71bbca976ccb6111fb75e8c2a03eeb/test/e2e/basic-specs.js#L26), tracking failures per test, but hooks cause trouble.  An error in a before block doesn't result in any failed tests objects, they're just [skipped](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L224), even though the runner records a failure.  Any ideas for catching hook failures as well?