# How to check in the teardown method of mocha (tdd) if the current test failed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, teardown

I know how to check if a test failed in the `afterEach()` method of mocha: That's explained here: [detecting test failures from within afterEach hooks in Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194672/detecting-test-failures-from-within-aftereach-hooks-in-mocha)

But what about the people using `suite` and `test` (tdd) instead of `describe` and `it`??

How can I check if the current test failed here? The same code won't work because `state` would be undefined:

```
  teardown(async () => {
    // check if failed:
    if (this.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
      console.log("fail");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it works a little bit different with tdd (using `suite` and `test`).

Accessing `this.ctx.currentTest` instead of `this.currentTest` worked for me.

**Example:**

```
if (this.ctx.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
  console.log(`'${this.ctx.currentTest.title}' failed`);
}
```