# How might I check if any jest tests failed from within an afterAll block?

Tags: jestjs, playwright

I am using jest with playwright to run the tests on my web application. I am recording videos for each test but as there are 100s of test which we are to running daily, we are going out of space on our server. so we decided to only save the videos of those test which has failed so my question is that is there any way i can know in the afterall block weather the test has failed or passed following is the code which i am using

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    // start the recording
})

afterAll(async()=>{
    // stop and save the recording if the test has failed other wise delete it
    // here i need to check if the test has failed or passed
});
```

I wanted this behaviour [How might I check if any mocha tests failed from within an after block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031765/how-might-i-check-if-any-mocha-tests-failed-from-within-an-after-block)

Comment: afterAll isn't a proper place for that, you have no access to this kind of data there. Check custom environment.

Comment: I am using jest with typescript, as far as i know the custom environmnet with typescript is not supported in the jest yet and its support is expected to be available in the jest 27

Comment: The question says nothing about TS. Do you mean https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1445 ? You can switch to JS for this file until then. Any way, custom environment is where it can be done.